# Mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes after adding admob ads library

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, admob, build.gradle

I Know there are many question like this, but didn't find any one with Admob ads  dependency, i just want to use Admob ads in my app, and i added the ads-dependency from official website `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'`.

But shows me this warning:

```
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 15.0.1, 15.0.0. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1   and com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)
```

I only want to use ads dependency only without the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

check your app-gradle file, you have a conflict in dependencies. Update the following

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
```

Comment: i only used _com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
_

Comment: there are other dependencies conflicting with google-services-ads. Please copy & paste all dependencies.

Comment: 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
     'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
     'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
     'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
     'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

Comment: okay i see that you are adding 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0' twice, add it only once, remove duplicate.

Comment: also update 15.0.0 to 15.0.1 for gms:play-services-ads. or copy following  line 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1', this should solve the problem.